# android WebView change color

Tags: android, background-color, android-webview

I want to change the background color of a webview when I press a button.. for that I use use webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); but the color never changes until I load something on the webview.. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you load a blank page in it?

Comment: The problem is that I use the webview as a chat board so I load in it messages and if I do that I will erase the data in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `invalidate()` on your `WebView` object. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29).

Comment: Could you please show the code where you create the `WebView` (or do you inflate your layout from a resource file?)

Comment: I am creating the WebView from code, here is the clickListener code: WebConversation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
WebConversation.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); 
WebConversation.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
//WebConversation.loadUrl("");WebConversation.buildDrawingCache();
WebConversation.invalidate();

Comment: Maybe the WebView has a size of zero when no content is loaded. You could try setting the layout height to FILL_PARENT. See View.setLayoutParams(); Maybe you have to call View.requestLayout() afterwards. But I would suggest you build your activity's content view from a resouce, where you could specify background color and view size in xml.

Comment: now I have tried requestLayout() too :( but no results.. I want to make it from code because I make chat rooms on the fly and dynamically and manage them by id's.. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Are you creating multiple WebViews on the fly? If not, you can create one in the resource file, give it an android:id like so: `<WebView android:id="@+id/my_id_constant"` and then get a reference to it later: `WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_id_constant);"`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am creating WebViews on the fly :(( and I cannot use that.

Comment: You said you have tried `requestLayout();`. Have you also called setLayoutParams before? And btw why would you need to create Webviews on the fly?

Comment: Yes, I am setting the WebView's layoutParams and I need to create WebViews on the fly because webView is my chat board and I create chat boards on the fly... I am working on a IM client..

Comment: Sorry, if this also doesn't work the only way I could think of is Mudassir's proposition: just load a blank page. `about:blank` for example.